# Problem with reasigning value to a list in Angular

Tags: html, typescript, angular7

hello I have a list of projects listOfPhasesWithTasks which I get from backEnd. I assigned it to a local variable filteredPhasesWithTasks which I'm using in the rest of the project. It is supposed to work as a backup. When I'm doing filtering like this :

```
 this.filteredPhasesWithTasks.forEach((phase) => {
                    phase.tasks = phase.tasks.filter(task => task.taskName !== null && task.taskName.toUpperCase().includes(filterParam.taskName.toUpperCase()));
                });
```

I don't get why this changes my listOfPhasesWithTasks as well. I'm expecting that it would change only filteredPhasesWithTasks as code says.

Comment: You can solve this by instead using `Array.prototype.map` and returning new `phase` objects rather than modifying like `phase.tasks =`. You object spread `const newPhase = { ...phase };` to create new objects in combination with filter that also returns a new array.

Comment: Can you create some sort of working example in StackBlitz including what the date roughly looks like and then I can try to help provide a solution

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript (and Typescript) objects are passed [by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35473404/pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript).

This means if you have an object and you assign it to a new one, you don't duplicate the object, you just have reference to the first object from both variables. Hence, changing a field in one of the variables you assigned "changes it for both". Actually, changes it to the only existing object that is pointed by both your variables :P

You could consider using the [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) method offered by the library [Lodash](https://lodash.com/). You'll find a lot of other useful shortcuts there :)

Comment: Maybe show an example of how `Array.prototype.map` or similar can be used to avoid modifying the original/backup `phase`

Comment: Thanks but I would rather not impleent new library into the Project :) I would prefer using Angular 7 method to do it, without any external library